# Excel formula/VBA to detect a property of a group of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vba

I have a large dataset in an Excel sheet where:

- column A: quote number
- column B: opportunity number
- column C: sales order number.

One quote number will have multiple opportunity numbers. A sales order number will be generated if an opportunity is closed. What I need is a formula that can flag a quote as "closed" status when all opportunities related to that quote have a sales order number. E.g.,

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
---------+----------+----------
  123    |  247689  | K123
  123    |  678889  | K456
  578    |  555678  | K889
  578    |  678999  |
```

For the above example quote 123 should be flagged as "closed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is somewhat similar to Doktoro Reichard’s. 
My answer assumes that your data are valid (no blank cells in Columns `A` or `B`)
but not that they are sorted.

I’ll use `2` and `1337` to represent the first and last rows where you have data;
adjust this to your situation.  In cell `D2` enter

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2=A$2:A$1337), --ISBLANK(C$2:C$1337))
```

Drag/fill this down to cell `D1337`. 
This will calculate the number of rows that have the same quote number (Column `A`)
as the current row and have a blank order number (Column `C`). 
This will be 0 for closed quotes and positive for open quotes.

Comment: @Jasmine: You’re welcome; I’m glad I could help.  If you believe that my answer is the best one, please accept it –– click on the check mark to the left of it.  When your [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/reputation) reaches 15, you will be able to vote “up” for _all_ the good answers –– to your own question(s) and other peoples’.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Asking](http://superuser.com/help/asking) section of the Super User [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column. I'll assume that your data is sorted, as it will make my work a little easier:

The formula for the 1st helper column (here designed as `D`) is the following:

```
=OR(IS.EMPTY(A1);IS.EMPTY(B1);IS.EMPTY(C1))
```

This will return `FALSE` if both the quote number, the opportunity number and the sales order number are filled. This will return `TRUE` if one is empty.

With this, you can now do an `=OR` on all helper cells that refer to the same quote number (this is where sorting helps). If all helper cells for the respective quote return `FALSE`, the following:

```
=IF(OR(D1:D2);"Open";"Closed")
```

will write "Closed" if all cells are `FALSE`.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but it appears to me that this answer assumes that there are exactly two rows (opportunities) for each quote.  Yes, that’s true for Jasmine’s _example data_, but the question says, “One quote number will have multiple opportunity numbers,” so I believe that you’re assuming too much.

Comment: Just for the example. Unfortunately, the ranges would have to be set individually; as you state correctly, there might be countless rows (hence why I referred the ease that is sorting).

Comment: So you’re suggesting that the OP should set cells `D2`, `D4`, `D7`, `D9`, `D17`, etc…, _manually_?

Comment: No. The `D` column, as stated, contains the first formula. Using those values the OP would create an `=IF` for each quote number. The range in the last formula would be the cells that match a single quote number. If I had to choose, however, I would probably go with your answer @Scott, it *seems* less contrived than mine.

Comment: Thanks Reichard! Your suggestion works but I will have to set the range manually. Due to huge data, it can be tedious. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: OK, I basically made a typo. ... // ... So you’re suggesting that the OP should set cells `E2`, `E4`, `E7`, `E9`, `E17`, etc…, _manually_?

Comment: Yes. However, both answers fail in some way to provide a simple way to check if a single quote number is open or closed.